# How do I make this kind of noise grunge effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, patterns, texture, illustrator-effects

[image]
[image]

How do I make this kind of noise grunge effect in Illustrator?
Have tried Pixelate effect but does not look good.
Thank you in advance for your answer!!

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE**. Please look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community, and what we're about. Look at [ask] and [answer] questions, to learn how to frame acceptable queries and what to expect of replies and answers; please also look at [help/behavior] to understand our community's internal behavioural expectations. You will get far better responses if you can clearly ***show*** what *you've* tried so far...

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the same as your examples... Especially the first one, but maybe it's close enough.

1. [Start with a white rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwAUF.png)
2. [`Effect > Artistic > Sponge...`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0yIl.png)

   - Definition and smoothness should be quite high.
3. `Object Expand Appearance` so that you can trace it.
4. [`Object > Image Trace > Make...`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGNvG.png)

   - Use `black & white` preset as the starting point.
   - Adjust the threshold and other sliders if needed.
   - Check `Ignore White`
   - Expand it

The result:
[image]

Comment: Good. Making it following your instructions I noticed that after applying the Sponge, we can apply an Effect>Sketch>Stamp to make it more smooth.